# Unable to generate valid JWT for authenticating with Google Functions - PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-functions, jwt

**Generating JWT:**

```
$time = time();

$header = '{"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT", "kid": "PRIVATE-KEY-ID-GIVEN-IN-JSON-FILE"}';

$payload = '{"iss": "*****@**********.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "sub": "*****@**********.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "aud": "https://***********.cloudfunctions.net/function-name/?uri=https://www.example.com", "exp": ' . ($time + 3600) . ', "iat": ' . $time . '}';

$key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n********\n*********\n***********\n******\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // this is from the json file

$header_encoded = base64url_encode($header);

$payload_encoded = base64url_encode($payload);

$jwt = $header_encoded . "." . $payload_encoded;

$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);

openssl_sign($header_encoded . "." . $payload_encoded, $signature, $pkeyid);

$jwt .= "." . base64url_encode($signature);
```

Now CURL to Google Cloud functions URL with this JWT as **Authorization: Bearer $jwt** returns 401 error.

**Generating Access Token:**

Trying to get Access token from OAUTH endpoint as per the documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#callinganapi

This returns an access token, however using the access token as auth bearer also throws 401.

---

The google functions code is working correctly. I have verified this with,

Running: `google cloud auth print-identity-token` in the terminal prints a signed JWT of my default account and passing this signed JWT as Auth Bearer, executes and proper 200 response code is returned.

---

Am I doing anything wrong in generating the JWT or access token? Or have I misunderstood or missed anything from the documentation?

Note:

1. I have tried `aud` key with Cloud Function trigger URL, `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` both didn't worked.
2. I have made the service account as owner with complete privileges.
3. I have also tried with adding `scope` in the payload as: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`, didn't worked.

---

**Function Defn of base64url_encode:**

```
function base64url_encode($data)
{
    $b64 = base64_encode($data);
    if ($b64 === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $url = strtr($b64, '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($url, '=');
}
```

Comment: According to the [**Required claims** section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest), you should be passing `iss`, `scope`, `aud`, `exp` and `iat` in your claimset, and to get an access token, `aud` should be exactly `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`. I'd start there maybe?

Comment: I checked with `iss, scope, aud, exp, iat`. I am able to get access token, however the access token is not working for cloud function. It's returning 401.

Comment: `iss` and `sub` are the service account email address. `scope` is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`, `aud` is `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, `iat` is current time and `exp` is time + 3600.